# Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I keep getting the following stack trace and am not sure what it means.

```
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidEndTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:73)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.checkLastTagWas(CodedInputStream.java:124)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:189)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:732)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:238)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:178)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:724)
```

- What does "Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag." mean?
- What is a "message end-group tag"?
- Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Groups in protobuf are written as a start/end numeric pair - kinda like how `<foo>` needs a `</foo>`, but in a different format. Essentially it is complaining that it found a `</bar>` instead (just: the xml is only a metaphor). The details are in the [encoding specification](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding), but the long and short is that one of:

- the data is inherently corrupt (either by damage of by a faulty encoder), or
- the data is becoming corrupt while reading, or
- the data is fine and you gave a faulty decoder

If I had to guess, the data has been damaged in transit - because [that is so frighteningly common](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html)

Comment: Would you guys please consider [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531899/how-to-write-a-valid-decoding-file-based-on-a-given-proto-reading-from-a-pb?noredirect=1#comment47219218_29531899)

Comment: Would you guys please consider this related question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71276445/kafka-consumer-net-protocol-message-end-group-tag-did-not-match-expected-tag