# the error about "grpc: error unmarshalling request: proto: mismatching end group marker"

Tags: go, grpc, protocols, grpc-go

i meet a go grpc error recently, but can't find the reason. orz

does anyone has idea about this error?

```
rpc error: code = Internal desc = grpc: error unmarshalling request: proto: mismatching end group marker
```

It seems there is something wrong about the proto in grpc, but i check the code and log find that they can match.

So i want to know the reason about this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105477/protocol-message-end-group-tag-did-not-match-expected-tag)